# CSS Dropdown Menu Alignment with Content

Tags: html, css, dropdown, navigationbar

I am currently trying to make a (responsive) navigation bar, and while I have already troubleshooted with it a lot I can't find my way through it. :(

I have 2 issues at the moment. 
1) In wide screen, I want to center the dropdown under its "button" title.
2) In smartphone/tablet screen, I want to make the dropdown, when appearing, push down the rest of the "button" titles and not covering them.

About 1, I have tried changing `right` and `left` attributes of the dropdown list but it justs sticks to the side of the screen no matter the changes I make to the `position` of dropdown list and parent element.

About 2, I have messed around with `position` but still I can't make it work as if it was static.

Ideally I would like to use just HTML and CSS.

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/SteliosKts/01o6cem5/10/

PS.I am sorry if it's a repost, it's just that I can't solve my prolbem although I have checked most of the relative threads

Comment: One thing you need is .dropdownItem {position:relative} and remove that from .dropdownList

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. remove `position:absolute;` from the `.dropdownItem:hover .dropdownList`.
2. change `display: block;` to `display: inline-block;` in `.dropdownList`.
3. remove `max-height: 55px` in `li:nth-child(n + 2)`
4. Add `flex-basis: 30px;` for mobile view.

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*------------Top Header & Logo------------*/

#background_Header {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #9a999b;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
}

#vertical_top_header_placeHolder {
  float: left;
  background-color: #9a999b;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
}

/*------------------------------------------*/

/*-------------------Navgiation Bar---------------*/

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  padding-left: 0px;
}

li {
  /* required for logo positioned in center */
  flex-basis: 90px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

li:first-child,
li:nth-child(n + 5) {
  order: 3;
}

li:first-child {
  flex-basis: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

li:nth-child(n + 2) {
  padding-top: 65px;
}

li:nth-child(6) {
  padding-top: 55px;
}

.dropdownItem:hover .dropdownList {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdownButton {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.dropdownList {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdownList a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------*/

/*---------------Smartphone Header Style---------------*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  li:first-child {
    background-color: #9a999b;
  }
  li {
    flex-basis: 30px;
  }
  #vertical_top_header_placeHolder {
    display: none;
  }
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------*/

/*---------------Vertical Navigation Style---------------*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .dropdownItem {}
  .dropdownButton {}
  .dropdownList {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
  li {
    flex-basis: 30px;
  }
  li:first-child,
  li:nth-child(n + 5) {
    order: 0;
  }
  li:nth-child(n + 2) {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700&subset=latin,greek" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600&subset=latin,greek-ext,greek" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  </head>

  <body>
    <!--<div id="vertical_Conteiner">-->
    <div id="vertical_top_header_placeHolder"></div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div id="background_Header">

          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdownItem">
          <a class="dropdownButton" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    Team 1
                </a>
          <div class="dropdownList">
            <a href="#">T1I1</a>
            <a href="#">T1I2</a>
            <a href="#">T1I3</a>
            <a href="#">T1I4</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdownItem">
          <a class="dropdownButton" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    Team 2
                </a>
          <div class="dropdownList">
            <a href="#">T2I1</a>
            <a href="#">T2I2</a>
            <a href="#">T2I3</a>
            <a href="#">T2I4</a>
            <a href="#">T2I5</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdownItem">
          <a class="dropdownButton" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    Team 3
                </a>
          <div class="dropdownList">
            <a href="#">T3I1</a>
            <a href="#">T3I2</a>
            <a href="#">T3I3</a>
            <a href="#">T3I4</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdownItem">
          <a class="dropdownButton" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    Team 4
                </a>
          <div class="dropdownList">
            <a href="#">T4I1</a>
            <a href="#">T4I2</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdownItem">
          <a class="dropdownButton" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    Team 5 BigWord
                </a>
          <div class="dropdownList">
            <a href="#">T5I1</a>
            <a href="#">T5I2</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdownItem">
          <a class="dropdownButton" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    Team 6
                </a>
          <div class="dropdownList">
            <a href="#">T6I1</a>
            <a href="#">Team6_BigItem2</a>
            <a href="#">T6I3</a>
            <a href="#">T6I4</a>
            <a href="#">T6I5</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <article>
      <div>

      </div>
    </article>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: That helped a lot! Problem 2 solved entirely, and Problem 1 has one small problem. The dropdown is centered, though when I hover over a title the emerging dropdown pushes the other li elements sideways to make room for the .dropdownList. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Make for desktop `.dropdownItem { width: 90px;}` and make `.dropdownList { width: 100%;`. Play with values to see better result. NOTE: 90px it the same value as `flex-basis` value

Comment: yeah i tried that but i dismissed it since it cant work nicely due to big difference among my droplists' items widths (the real ones not those of the demo). Also, while this seems to be working on the x axis it doesnt on the y axis. I mean when the <article> section is added , below navbar, it will just push it down too. The thing is that while pushing the content down is wanted in mobile view, in wide view dropdown should overlay over any neighbor content (just like it was in the demo, but centered).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the absolute from here and you will see the dropdown list in large screen some below your button and in small screen too it will come below the button:

```
.dropdownItem:hover .dropdownList {display: block;/*   position: absolute; */}
```